# add divs using jquery inside a list item

Tags: jquery

I have a list item:

```
<li class="sortedli">Call Type</li>
```

I wish to add two div's on either side of the text in the list:

```
<li class="sortedli">
    <div class="sel-display-on">&nbsp;</div>
                Call Type
    <div class="sel-trash-on">&nbsp;</div>
</li>
```

How may I add this using Jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `prepend()` and `append()`;

```
$(".sortedli").prepend("<div class=\"sel-display-on\"></div>");
$(".sortedli").append("<div class=\"sel-trash-on\"></div>");
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HD9B8/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but I'd suggest:

```
var li = $('.sortedli').first();
$('<div />', {'class' : 'sel-display-on', 'text' : '&nbsp;'}).prependTo(li);
$('<div />', {'class' : 'sel-trash-on', 'text' : '&nbsp;'}).appendTo(li);
```

You could also, use:

```
$('.sortedli').html(
    function(i,h) {
        return '<div class="sel-display-on">&nbsp;</div>' + h + '<div class="sel-trash-on">&nbsp;</div>';
    });
```

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- `html()`.
- [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).

Comment: Also I think `$('.sorted1')` should be `$('.sortedli')`. good use of using a var instead of calling the `$` again.. but not sure why you want to use `.first()`.

Comment: I chose to use `first()` simply because I had, and *have*, no idea if the OP wants to do this to *every* element that matches the selector, or simply that particular one (which may not be the first in his actual code, but...I can only work with what we're given).

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
$("#content ul").append('< li > divs ... < / li >');
```