# Adding two divs either side of text in a list item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a function which receives a list item. When it does, I want to add two divs to either side of the text in the list item: FOr example, when it receives the item:

```
<li class="sortedli">
  Call Type
</li>
```

it should become:

```
<li class="sortedli">
   <div class="sel-display-on">&nbsp;</div>
       Call Type
   <div class="sel-trash-on">&nbsp;</div>
</li>
```

However, my function

```
receive: function (event, ui) {
   $(this).prepend("<div class=\"sel-display-on\"></div>");
   $(this).append("<div class=\"sel-trash-on\"></div>");
}
```

Produces this markup:

```
<div class="sel-display-on"></div>
<li class="sortedli" style="">Caller Id</li>
<div class="sel-trash-on"></div>
```

How may I rectify this?

Comment: Did you try out all solutions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163556/add-divs-using-jquery-inside-a-list-item

Comment: What jQuery UI widget are you using.. the `receive` function looks like a callback function.. and so the `this` may not the `li` element.

Comment: @Vega - It's obviously not, and based on the output it's the `li`'s parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending/prepending to `.sortedli`'s parent. Use context to find the right element:

```
receive: function (event, ui) {
   $('.sortedli', this).prepend("<div class=\"sel-display-on\"></div>");
   $('.sortedli', this).append("<div class=\"sel-trash-on\"></div>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer all. I am using JqueryUI sortable. The problem I have now encountered is that once I add another list item, I get duplicates of the appended and prepended markup.

Comment: Well, yes! That is because `this` is the parent, and you're targeting all `.sortedli` inside the parent. You somehow have to find the right `li` element, or you could always filter the selector to exclude `li` elements that already have the two other elements added by just filtering for length or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
receive: function (event, ui) {
   $(this).html(function (idx, oldhtml) {
      return "<div class=\"sel-display-on\">&nbsp;</div>" + 
             oldhtml + 
             "<div class=\"sel-trash-on\">&nbsp;</div>";
}
```

---

> What jQuery UI widget are you using.. the receive function looks like
>   a callback function.. and so the this may not the li element. – Vega
>
> @Vega - It's obviously not, and based on the output it's the li's
>   parent. – adeneo 44 secs ago

If the above didn't work, try below..

```
receive: function (event, ui) {
   $('.sortedli', this).html(function (idx, oldhtml) {
      return "<div class=\"sel-display-on\">&nbsp;</div>" + 
             oldhtml + 
             "<div class=\"sel-trash-on\">&nbsp;</div>";
}
```